# 'Bd' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

We sometimes get the error above in the start of our wpf application. It seems to happen in the Loaded event of the main window of our application, but it is hard to pinpoint exactly, because it happens almost never for the majority of our users. A few users seem to get it almost every time, though. As it is very hard to reproduce, do anyone know where we should begin to look?

Regards,
Øyvind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably in the style of some control where you use a control named "Bd". look in triggers, setters and storyboards!

Comment: I will try that. Actually there are a few controls (borders) named "Bd", but I have also seen some built-in control templates with controls named Bd. As a first step, I have renamed all of my own "Bd"'s and will wait until the error happens again.